# Error during WebSocket handshake,Unexpected response code: 502 using elasticache redis and elastic beanstalk

Tags: websocket, redis, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, django-channels, amazon-elasticache

I am using django channels 2 and it is currenly working on localhost when I am using a redis server in Ubuntu in localhost. I had deployed my django project on elastic beanstalk and I am using elasticache redis 5. I have followed these tutorials https://hackernoon.com/setting-up-django-channels-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk-716fd5a49c4a and https://medium.com/@anish.shrestha/django-channels-2-0-and-aws-elastic-beanstalk-ab814bb15c4b. My .ebextesions has configurations [env.config file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0GHn.png) and [setup.config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWIP3.png) and daemon.config as shown in the tutorials. I have set the elastic beanstalk instance and elasticache redis on the same vpc and availability zone. I have set the inbound rule of the security groups to receive tcp on port 6379. Still I get the error of websocket unable to connect. This is the snapshot of how I am sending request to channels [websocket connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6VKi.png). It works on localhost I am having trouble getting it to work on aws elasticache and elastic beanstalk. If anyone can provide some guidance that would be really helpful I am stuck on this for quite a long time now.

Comment: Hi there - I'm dealing with many of the same tutorials and issues. Still having problems with my supervisorctl and daphne workers. Did you ever figure this out or no dice?